# External connection to SQL server using PYODBC

Tags: sql, pyodbc

I want to connect to an external database using python to extract the data. I have allowed remote access through SSMS, created inbound rules in the firewall for port 1433,  and enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server Network Configuration.
However, I am still facing issues using pyodbc with the following string:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                  'SERVER=51.175.xxx.xx,1433\INSTANCE;'
                  'DATABASE=SAMPLE;'  
                  'uid=User;'
                  'pwd=Password;')
```

When running it provides the error message:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. 
(17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')
```

Any suggestions on how to address this issue? I am positive it is a server problem, as I am able to locally access the database with pyodbc using uid and pwd.

Comment: Local access has nothing to do with remote access, so you need to check if at least the host and port are available from your external network. It is not [a programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be addressed to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or [DBA Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Try to make an ODBC connection in ODBC manager, to make sure that you can access this database from the computer.